# how to disable swipe vertical scrollin MGSwipeTableCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

when the table is created I want swipe vertical scrolling to be disabled (don't show the MGSwipeButton) but I also want that when clicking on a button this displacement is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below delegate methods,

```
/**
 * Delegate method to enable/disable swipe gestures
 * @return YES if swipe is allowed
 **/
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell canSwipe:(MGSwipeDirection) direction;
/**
 * Delegate method invoked when the current swipe state changes
 @param state the current Swipe State
 @param gestureIsActive YES if the user swipe gesture is active. No if the uses has already ended the gesture
 **/
-(void) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell didChangeSwipeState:(MGSwipeState) state gestureIsActive:(BOOL) gestureIsActive;
```